# Problems installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu 14.04 in Virtual Box some strange codes pop up and no matter what I do.

Am I doing something wrong? A few hours before I successfully installed Windows XP SP3, but now this Ubuntu just won’t install?

[image]

Comment: Make sure virtual machine type is correctly set up (operating system family and 32/64bit). Try to change virtual hardware (chipset especially)

Comment: @Dan LOL my bad I chose 64 bit for 32 bit. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall system (VM) using right architecture (x86/x64) and latest version of VirtualBox. Also you should re-download Ubuntu image to verify that current image is not corrupted during download.

Comment: My internet speed is so slow it takes 7 hours to download that 900 MB. But strange thing is that when I boot ubuntu from pendrive its okay and about VM I just downloaded latest version!

Comment: To verify the image just check the md5 sum, no need to redownload